# OserverCommandGetGephi ClassNotFoundException OrientDB 3.0.6

Tags: classnotfoundexception

Environment :

```
Docker   : version 1.12.6
Linux    : Centos 7
Java     : Java 1.8.0_45
OrientDB : 3.0.6
```

Am trying to invoke OrientDB instance from an image built up using the Dockerfile from https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docker/blob/bc7e1c48bedbd259df885dd922a13f79dfef0107/3.0/x86_64/alpine/Dockerfile.

when run the image i get an exception in the middle of the start up process

```
2018-09-04 07:28:30:865 INFO  - shutdown storage: OSystem... [OrientDBDistributed]Error during server execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create custom command invoking the constructor: com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.server.command.OServerCommandGetGephi(com.orientechnologies.orient.server.config.OServerCommandConfiguration@501d7d86)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.createCommand(OServerNetworkListener.java:129)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.<init>(OServerNetworkListener.java:88)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:453)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain$1.run(OServerMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.server.command.OServerCommandGetGephi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerNetworkListener.createCommand(OServerNetworkListener.java:123)
```

While am able to download the same OrientDB bits and start up the instance directly (without using docker) thru the $ORIENT_HOME/bin/server.sh script.

Any help in resolving this issue ?

Please let me know.

Comment: Strange, but true.   After some good research, i found a couple of ClassNotFound, errors, i got the Orient DB 3.0.6 up and running now.

Comment: 1. There were 2 Classes that were reported "missing" in the /lib/ folder.  They are OServerCommandGetGephi and IndexableGraph from tinkerpop blueprints.

Comment: 2. Am sure, these 2 classes were repackaged into other existing jars, but seems like their references thru object injection configurations need to fixed.

Comment: 3. After i added their corresponding JARs orientdb-graphdb-3.0.1.jar and blueprints-core-2.6.0.jar respectively  to the lib folder thru the Dockerfile, and rebuild the image, OrientDB 3.0.6 is up and running.  Still there are few more JARs that need to be added for GREMLIN language support and etc.